# I would like to ask about PHPUnit of Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, phpunit, drupal-8

I created Block in Drupal 8 with a custom module.

Is it possible to implement this with PHPUnit?
If you can implement it please tell me how.

I want to realize the test with PHPUnit below.

I would be pleased if you could reply just whether it was possible or not.

moduleNameBlock.php

```
/**
 * @file
 * create block
 */

namespace Drupal\moduleName\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 *
 * Provides a 'testBlock' block.
 * @Block(
 *   id = "test_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Test"),
 *   category = @Translation("Menu"),
 * )
 */
class moduleNameBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build()
  {
    $build = [];
    $url   = '';
    $nid   = '';

    $nid = $this->getCurrentUserNode();
    if ( !empty($nid) ) {
      $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid]);
    }
    $block = [
      '#theme' => 'block_theme',
      '#url'   => $url,
      '#nid'   => $nid,
      '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0
      ]
    ];
    $build['test_block'] = $block;
    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * The node associated with the user
   * @return nid
   */
  private function getCurrentUserNode() {
    $user_id = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    $nid     = $user_id->get('field_name')->getValue();

    return $nid[0]['target_id'];
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by writing a PHPUnit Functional test.

In your module directory create the following structure `/tests/src/Functional` then create a file like `ModuleNameBlockTest.php` then you can place the block in the `setUp` function and create tests to test the block.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\my_module_name\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

/**
 * Class ModuleNameBlockTest.
 *
 * @package Drupal\Tests\my_module_name\Functional
 * @group my_group
 */
class ModuleNameBlockTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['block', 'my_module_name'];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $adminUser = $this->drupalCreateUser(['administer blocks']);
    $this->drupalLogin($adminUser);
    $this->drupalPlaceBlock('my_block_name');
    $this->drupalLogout($adminUser);
  }

  /**
   * Test the block.
   */
  public function testMyAwesomeBlock() {
    // Your test logic here.
  }

}
```

You can always look into the source code of Drupal for some examples. E.g. `UserBlocksTest.php` of the core user module.